# Running Selenium test cases on Linux Redhat

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have the following error when trying to launch chrome browser on Linux:

> `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException`: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:37423/

- ChromeDriver 2.36
- Google Chrome 65.0.3325.162

C# code run using mono:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Close();
```

Comment: That's a very generic error message. I doubt that you will find a solution here without providing way more information about your whole setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what kind of info i may provide ?

Comment: I can't tell. Just imagine some of your friends asks *"Can you help me? My Selenium doesn't work anymore."* and then he provides you with exactly the information you give us in your question. Would you be able to help him? Probably not. It's like *"My computer crashed, help."*, we could only guess the reason, there are so many. An answer on SO should not guess, it should completely solve the issue, without any further questions. And that's simply not possible at the moment.